# PHP regex matching to get a decimal number

Tags: php, regex

I have been using a regex expression as follows. My aim is to extract a once decimal point number like 8.4 from a string. The code I have used is:

```
$reg = "/[0-9]+[ ]+([0-9]\.[0-9])/";
preg_match_all($reg, $buffer, $matches);
```

For an input like

```
0000001222   86257   8.4
```

I am getting the array $matches as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86257   8.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8.4
        )

)
```

Why is the pattern matched 2 times? I would like my matches array to be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8.4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Match #0 in a regular expression is (almost) always the *entire* matched string. In your case, because you're using parentheses (a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)) you're telling the expression to capture a subset of the matched string too. Capture groups are returned starting from match #1.

If you explicitly don't want to capture the full string, consider using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead; note that you'll need to refactor your expression a bit because lookarounds in PHP lookbehinds need to be zero-width, and thus quantifiers (the +) are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (`PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is the default):

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So in your case the result you want will be always in `$matches[1]`.